C++ Large Heap Array Initialisation
I am writing code which demands a large array. I am told that, due to the size of the array, it is best to store this in Heap Memory. I need this array to be unsigned because I am using it to store data at the BIT level.
    const int mapWidth = 100;
    const int mapHeight = 100;

int main()
    unsigned int* empireMap = new unsigned int[(mapWidth * mapHeight) + 1] {};

When I compile the code, I get the following error:
Warning C26495  
Variable 'sf::Glyph::lsbDelta' is uninitialized. 
Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   

I have to admit that, although I understand that any variable must be initialised before use, I don't understand what this error is telling me. sf::Glyph::lsbDelta?  I do appreciated that similar questions on this topic have been asked but the don't seem to be specific enough for my needs.
Any assistance would be appreciated.
Moon.
I have tried adding a zero in to the curly brackets
    unsigned int* empireMap = new unsigned int[(mapWidth * mapHeight) + 1] {0};

but this has not affected the fault.

Where is the line of code that the error message refers to?

You are talking about an error, but the message is  a warning. If your code runs, I think you can safely ignore the warning. See also the same question on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/sfml/comments/152tmzb/warning_in_sfml_what_does_it_mean/?rdt=34489

Thanks Oldboy. The line that defines the array is the line that gives the error. I am using Visual Studio 2022 with the SFML library pluggin.

Thanks Lex W.  Yes the code runs. When I first started in coding with C++, I used to get pile of warnings for things like potential data loss for conversion between INT and Float variables. Made it difficult to see wood from the trees. Use STATIC_CAST now and get very few errors. I wanted to solve this one but as you say it can be ignored and I don't think it's a quick fix. Interestingly, I started getting this following an upgrade from SFML version 2.5, to SFML version 2.6. Maybe a bug? I will leave it.

Use std::vector instead of using 'new'. No related to the error message, but it's standard practice for c++ heap arrays
